# Felix 'pref' bundle requires 'log version >=1.3', but D/L 'log' bundle version = 1.0

Tags: osgi, bundle, apache-felix

the Felix download page shows
 Log bundle         version 1.0.0
 Preferences bundle version 1.0.2

But preferences requires log-bundle version >= 1.3

It just want to get an idea of how 'preferences' works, 
so any log compatible bundle is welcome :)

Regards.

Comment: For some reason i ran unto a problem which isn't there anymore.. i didn't save any errorlog.

But it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the Felix log bundle version (1.0.0) with the required version of the OSGi log service (1.3). This is similar to the difference between the Tomcat version and the version of the Servlet API that it supports.

Felix Log 1.0.0 provides `org.osgi.service.log;version=1.3` so you should be fine.

In general, the version of a bundle is not relevant as OSGi bundles do not depend on other bundles directly, but on the package versions they provide.

(I need to check, but you may also need the OSGi service compendium JAR file which defines the log interface, Felix Log is just one possible implementation of that service).

Comment: I've checked my log bundle's manifest and you're correct.  it says
  Export-Package: org.osgi.service.log;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.3"
and Prefs manifest says
 Import-Package: org.apache.felix.prefs,org.osgi.framework;version="1.3
 ",org.osgi.service.log;version="1.3",org.osgi.service.prefs;version="
 1.1",org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.3"

Strange.. i really did see a runtime error, but all the output to prove that is gone :(  
i've got it running just now without using other bundles?!
Still, Thanks for the info